# How to use loops in symbolic expression in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I encounter a trouble when using the **nchoosek** function in Matlab,

the Warning is:`Result may not be exact. Coefficient is greater than 9.007199e+15 and is only accurate to 15 digits.`

So I decide to try the symbolic expression, just as:

```
evalin(symengine,'nchoosek(100,50)')
```

It functions well,but I want to loop the expression,for example:

```
 for i=1:50;
    c(i)=evalin(symengine,'nchoosek(50,i)'); end
```

But It doesn't work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `i` is a number and not setecetd in the string part, you should create the string by casting the value of `i` to the string. Hence, you can try:

```
for i=1:50
    c(i)=evalin(symengine,['nchoosek(50,',num2str(i),')']); 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Much easier to use [`feval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/feval.html) than `evalin` in this case so that you don’t have to manually convert from integer to string:

```
for i = 1:50
    c(i) = feval(symengine, 'nchoosek', 50, i);
end
```

But you don’t really need to do this at all. You can just call the symbolic version of [`nchoosek`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/nchoosek.html) by making sure that at least one of the input arguments is symbolic:

```
for i = 1:50
    c(i) = nchoosek(sym(50),i);
end
```

Comment: Great, I will try